# Why does my powershell function fail to be called from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-sdk

Trying to use a powershell script with a function as follows:

```
    function MoveCompressFiles{
 Param
    (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true )]
         [string] $Des,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [string] $Src
    )
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing 
$files = Get-ChildItem $Src 
 foreach ($f in $files) {    
    if (($f.Length / 1KB) -lt [int32]200) {
        Copy-Item -Path $f.FullName -Destination $Des
    } 
    else {      
       Copy-Item -Path $f.FullName -Destination $Des
        while (((Get-Item (($Des).ToString() + "\$f")).Length / 1KB ) -gt 500) {
            $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile((($Des).ToString() + "$f"))
            [int32]$new_width = $img.Width * (20 / 100);
            [int32]$new_height = $img.Height * (20 / 100);
            $img2 = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($new_width, $new_height)
            $graph = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($img2)
            $graph.DrawImage($img, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height)
            $newImgName = "M".ToString() + $f.ToString()
            $img2.Save(($Des).ToString()+"\$newImgName")
            $img.Dispose()
            $img2.Dispose()
            Remove-Item ($Des.ToString()+$f)
            Rename-Item -Path ($Des.ToString()+$newImgName) -NewName "$f"            
            Write-Host ((Get-Item ($Des.ToString()+$f)).Length / 1KB )
        } 
        $filesize = $f.Length * 0.8
        $filesize=($filesize / 1KB)
        #$filesize = [math]::round(($filesize / 1KB), 0)
        $abc = "KB"
        $filesizeSTR = $filesize.ToString() + $abc
        Push-Location $Src
        mogrify -path $Des -define jpeg:extent=$filesizeSTR $f
        Pop-Location
        Write-Host "Moved file $f"
    } 
}
}
```

Works in Powershell, however when i try to do it it in my solution,

```
private static void Powershell()
        {
            string SCRIPT_PATH = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Untitled2.ps1");
           using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                runspace.Open();
                PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
                ps.Runspace = runspace;
                ps.AddScript(SCRIPT_PATH);
                ps.Invoke();
                ps.AddCommand("MoveCompressFiles").AddParameters(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Des" , @"C:\Des"},
                    {"Src", @"C:\Src"}
                });
            }
     }
```

It doesn't work, I've tried some other methods of calling a function from a ps script but it still fails to even move the files to another location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **you need to [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) your script file (`. <script>`) in order to make the `MoveCompressFiles` function available**, which requires an `.AddScript()` call,
I suggest constructing a single piece of PowerShell code in a string variable that both dot-sources the script and invokes your function via a single `.AddScript()` call.

However, in order **to guarantee that `.AddScript()` works, you must first ensure that the [PowerShell execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies) allows script invocation**, using a call to `Set-ExecutionPolicy`; the code below uses `-Scope Process`, so as to limit the change to the current process.

- *Update*: There's a simpler way to configure the execution policy, via the *initial session state* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942672/45375).

```
var SCRIPT_PATH = @"C:\Untitled2.ps1";
var src = @"C:\Src";
var des = @"C:\Des";
var script = $@". ""{SCRIPT_PATH}""; MoveCompressFiles -Des ""{des}"" -Src ""{src}""";

using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
  // Make sure that script execution is allowed.
  ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy")
        .AddParameter("Scope", "Process")
        .AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass")
        .AddParameter("Force", true);
  ps.Invoke();

  // Add the PowerShell code constructed above and invoke it.
  ps.AddScript(script);
  // Use foreach (var o in ps.Invoke()) { Console.WriteLine(o); } to print the output.
  ps.Invoke();
}
```

<sup>Note the simplified, *implicit* runspace creation, by using `PowerShell.Create()` only.</sup>

The embedded PowerShell code dot-sources your script file (`. <script>`) in order to define the `MoveCompressFiles` function, and then invokes the function.

Note that the above, as your own code, doesn't capture or print the output from the PowerShell code (`.Invoke()`'s output).

To see if errors occurred, you can check `ps.HadErrors` and examine `ps.Streams.Error` or any of the other streams, such as `.ps.Streams.Information` for the `Write-Host` output (the *success* stream's output is what `.Invoke()` returns directly).

For instance, use something like the following to print all errors (messages only) that occurred to the console's standard error stream:

```
foreach (var o in ps.Streams.Error) {
  Console.Error.WriteLine(o);
}
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `ps.AddScript(SCRIPT_PATH); ps.Invoke();`

While this *executes* your script, it does so in a *child scope*, so the embedded function `MoveCompressFiles` definition is *not* added to your session's top-level scope, so the subsequent `.AddCommand()` call fails, because the `MoveCompressFiles` function isn't available.

Instead, you must [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#dot-sourcing-operator-) your script (`. <script>`), which makes it run in the caller's scope and therefore makes its function definition available there.

As an aside: Despite the `.AddScript()` method's name, its primary purpose is to execute a *piece of PowerShell code*, not a script *file*.
To execute the latter (without dot-sourcing), use `.AddCommand()`.