# How to execute a powershell script using c# and setting execution policy?

Tags: c#, powershell, executionpolicy, powershell-sdk

I tried to combine two answers from stackoverflow ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments) & [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140309/set-execution-policy-from-process))

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
// Override ExecutionPolicy

PropertyInfo execPolProp = iss.GetType().GetProperty(@"ExecutionPolicy");
if (execPolProp != null && execPolProp.CanWrite)
{
    execPolProp.SetValue(iss, ExecutionPolicy.Bypass, null);
}
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

//Here's how you add a new script with arguments
Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile);
CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("key","value");
myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);

pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

// Execute PowerShell script
results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

In my powershell script I have the following parameter:

```
Param(
[String]$key
)
```

However, when I execute this, then I get the following exception:

```
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. 
The argument is null or empty. 
Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without knowing what your specific problem was, note that your C# code can be greatly streamlined, which may also resolve your problem:

- There is no need to resort to *reflection* in order to set a session's execution policy.
- Using an instance of the [`PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell) class greatly simplifies command invocation.

```cs
// Create an initial default session state.
var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
// Set its script-file execution policy (for the current session only).
iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Bypass;

// Create a PowerShell instance with a runspace based on the 
// initial session state.
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(iss);

// Add the command (script-file call) and its parameters, then invoke.
var results =
  ps
   .AddCommand(scriptfile)
   .AddParameter("key", "value")
   .Invoke();
```

Note: The `.Invoke()` method only throws an exception if a *terminating* error occurred during execution of the PowerShell script. The more typical *non-terminating* errors are instead reported via `.Streams.Error`.

Comment: This is interesting. So, in C# you don't have to mark a line continuation like you would in PowerShell (i.e. : the backtick ( ` ) )?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala: There is no line-continuation char. in C#, because the logic is reversed: a statement, irrespective of how many lines it spans, is only terminated by `;` In PowerShell, which doesn't require explicit statement termination, you can _situationally_ get away without a line-ending backtick, namely when the statement is unambiguously _incomplete_, notably after a line-ending `|` and, similarly, but not identically, to the `ps` example above: a line-ending `.` - that is, the `.` must be at the _end_ of the line for PowerShell to know that the statement continues.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala: As an explicit exception, _PowerShell (Core) 7+_ now allows you to place a `|` on the _next_ line in order to continue a pipeline. That is, while Windows PowerShell only supports, e.g. `Get-Date |<newline> Format-List`, PowerShell (Core) 7+ now also supports `Get-Date<newline>| Format-List`, albeit only in _scripts_, because _interactively_ `Get-Date` would execute by itself before you get a chance to continue the statement (except inside `{ ... }`).