# Visual Studio can't execute a Powershell script due to execution policy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2022, executionpolicy

I'm trying to run a basic powershell script in a c# application, but I can't seem to get it to run. I've tried this code with and without the added execution policy code in the pipeline creation and have gotten the same results.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned");


        pipeline.Commands.Add(@"C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\testScript.ps1");

        // Execute PowerShell script
        var results = pipeline.Invoke();
    }
```

The error I receive is this:

System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: 'File C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\testScript.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.'](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.%27)

When I run "get-executionpolicy -list", my execution policy seems to be fine.

[image]

Comment: Did you download or transfer `testScript.ps1` from somewhere else? You can remove zone data attached to the file with `Unblock-File` after which you should be able to execute it.

Comment: nope, i just created a brand new ps1 file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Normally, the persistently configured script [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies)  applies to *PowerShell SDK*-based projects such as yours, too.
- While your [`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy) `-List` output implies that `RemoteSigned` is the effective policy (as reported when you *omit* `-List`), the color of your screenshots suggest that you were asking for *Windows PowerShell*'s policy, which is separate from the execution policy for the cross-platform, install-on demand [*PowerShell (Core) v6+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition.
- Therefore, your inability to execute a *local* script - which `RemoteSigned` should allow - can have one of two causes:

  - If you project is based on the SDK for *PowerShell (Core) v6+* (via the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/) NuGet package), you'd have to consult - and possibly modify - *its* effective execution policy (run `pwsh -c Get-ExecutionPolicy` to see the policy in effect)

    - If you don't actually have PowerShell (Core) 6+ itself installed (i.e if you're only using its *SDK*), use the solution in the bottom section - which may be preferable anyway.
  - As Mathias points out in a comment, another possible reason is that your local script may have been downloaded *from the web*, via a web browser, in which case it is considered a *remote* file for the purpose of the execution policy. Passing its file path to [`Unblock-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file) as a one-time action should fix the problem.

---

Taking a step back:

**If you trust the local script to invoke, you can *bypass* the execution policy *for your application only*, by configuring your PowerShell SDK session accordingly** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942672/45375).

Comment: I ended up using the linked solution at the bottom, it worked, thanks for the help