Standard solution for "running scripts is disabled on this system" error not working in Windows 11
I know this topic has been discussed many times and I've browsed this forum in search of an answer but this issue I'm getting looks to be linked specifically to Windows 11.
So I recently moved from Windows 10 to Windows 11 and took the opportunity to install VS2022.
I have a C# console app that executes some Powershell script.  With my old setup (Win10 and VS2019), I was getting the "running scripts is disabled on this system" error message.  To fix this issue, I had to update the execution policy using the following command:
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Everything was working fine...until I tried upgrading my console app to VS2022 (on Win11).  For some unknown reason, the "Set-ExecutionPolicy" doesn't fix the issue anymore, I'm still getting the same error message.  I tried many variations like changing the scope, or using the "Unrestricted" policy, even turning on script execution in Group Policy, yet I'm still getting the same error.
Could it be some new Windows 11 setting that is causing this ?

Those scripts may have been marked as 'downloaded from the internet', especially if you copied them over from another PC? Try Unrestricted instead of RemoteSigned, or use Unblock-File /path/to/file.ps1 on those scripts, and see if they run?

Are you own a corporate network?  A bug may of been fixed or a new bug created.  You probably do not have the permission to change the policy.  Your domain may of changed or the domain of the machine may of changed and now you do not have the credentials in new domain.

I've already tried "Unrestricted".  Didn't test "Unblock-File" yet.  I mean, everything was working fine prior to me upgrading to Win11.

I am NOT on a corporate network, just my own personal rig at home.  Win11 Pro installed.

@Cpt.Whale these are scripts that a created myself and when I "upgraded" to Win11, I actually did a new install, using same credentials.

Run Get-ExecutionPolicy -List in the new console to see what the policy settings are on your system. They have priority in this order: MachinePolicy > UserPolicy > Process > CurrentUser > LocalMachine. I think Get-ExecutionPolicy by itself should return the effective policy setting. For example, if your VS2022 console starts powershell with a specific policy, it would be at the Process level, which takes priority. If you run VS as Admin/another user, the "CurrentUser" scope means it won't apply

@Cpt.Whale
MachinePolicy: Undefined, UserPolicy: Undefined, Process: Undefined, CurrentUser: RemoteSigned, LocalMachine: Unrestricted.
What's odd is that I'm using the same execution policy that I used when I was on Win10, which was RemoteSigned on CurrentUser.  The Unrestricted on LocalMachine is there just because I'm currently testing various solutions, to no avail.

Does the powershell console give you the same error when trying to run a script, or is it only when run by your app? How is the app executing the powershell script?

@Cpt.Whale I completely forgot to try that.  Tested it a few moments ago from PowerShell ISE and it ran with no issues.

Take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71473728/7411885, and maybe read through some of the explanation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022 . It depends on how you are executing the script - did you compile an app that runs a ps1 script, or launch powershell in the integrated console?

@Cpt.Whale yup, that was it.  The answer in that 1st link did it for me.  So basically when I updated my console app using VS2022, I switched to the Core framework and didn't know that my Powershell version (v5.1) was using Windows PowerShell's policy, and that I now needed to have the Core version. So I installed PowerShell v7, opened it, updated the execution policy and now I can execute ps1 scripts from VS2022.  Thx !
