# Why am I getting errors when running PowerShell command "Get-WindowsCapability" in .NetCore console application?

Tags: powershell, .net-core

New to PowerShell in .NetCore and the script works fine in PowerShell ISE, but when I run through my console application.

**Here is the script:**

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Microsoft.Windows.Notepad*
```

**Here is the output through PowerShell ISE:**

> Name         : Microsoft.Windows.Notepad~~~~0.0.1.0 State        :
> Installed DisplayName  : Notepad Description  : View, edit, and search
> through plain text documents and source code files instantly.
> DownloadSize : 301710 InstallSize  : 647868

**Here is my code snippet from my .NetCore console application:**

```
var psInstance = PowerShell.Create();
psInstance.AddScript("Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Microsoft.Windows.Notepad*");
var output  = psInstance.Invoke();
psInstance?.Runspace?.Close();

if (psInstance.HadErrors)
{
   var error = psInstance.Streams.Error.Select(e => e.ToString());
}
```

**Here is the error I'm seeing in my pInstance object:**

> Count = 5
> [0]: "The 'Get-WindowsCapability' command was found in the module 'Dism', but the module could not be loaded due to the following error:
> [File
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Dism\Dism.psm1
> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
> For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.]\r\nFor more
> information, run 'Import-Module Dism'."
> [1]: "The 'Get-WindowsCapability' command was found in the module 'Dism', but the module could not be loaded due to the following error:
> [File
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Dism\Dism.psm1
> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
> For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.]\r\nFor more
> information, run 'Import-Module Dism'."
> [2]: "[localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request.
> The following error with errorcode 0x8009030e occurred while using
> Negotiate authentication: A specified logon session does not exist. It
> may already have been terminated.  \r\n Possible causes are:\r\n  -The
> user name or password specified are invalid.\r\n  -Kerberos is used
> when no authentication method and no user name are specified.\r\n
> -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.\r\n  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.\r\n  -The client and remote computers are in
> different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.\r\n
> After checking for the above issues, try the following:\r\n  -Check
> the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.\r\n  -Change
> the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM
> TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.\r\n Note th
> at computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.\r\n
> -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
> about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.\r\n Other Possible Cause:\r\n
> -The domain or computer name was not included with the specified credential, for example: DOMAIN\UserName or COMPUTER\UserName."
> [3]: "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or
> empty, and then try the command again."
> [4]: "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Id'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the
> command again."

I a running the console app as Administrator.
Why does the script run successfully through PowerShell IDE, but throw errors through the sample app?

Is there something I additionally have to do to my PowerShell instance object?

Comment: Check `[enum]::GetNames( [Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicyScope]) | ForEach-Object {@{$_ = Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope $_}}` (and  [edit] your question to improve your [mcve] with that info, please).

Comment: @JosefZ - Not sure I follow you with the Check [enum] comment. The edited code snippet works fine cut & paste. Can you pls elaborate? Thx

Comment: Works fine. of course… But is a difference if you run it in `ISE` and your problematic environment (`PowerShell.exe` or `pwsh.exe`?) - both elevated and _normal_?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- Configure your PowerShell SDK-based session with an [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) that permits script execution, such as `RemoteSigned`
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942672/45375) for an example.

---

##### Background information.

The obsolescent<sup>[1]</sup> Windows PowerShell ISE invariably runs *Windows PowerShell*, whereas your .NET (Core) C# application of necessity uses *PowerShell (Core)*'s SDK.

The two PowerShell editions have *separate* execution policies, and it sounds like while *Windows PowerShell* on your system is configured to permit script execution, *PowerShell (Core)* is not.

It may be surprising that the `Dism` *module*, which `Get-WindowsCapability` is a part of, is subject to the *script* execution policy, given that modules aren't *`.ps1` script files*.

However, *many* modules are, namely if they (also) contain *PowerShell* code, which is not only true for *script* modules that are entirely implemented in PowerShell code (`*.psm1`), but also for primarily *binary* modules (those that provide their cmdlets via assemblies, i.e. compiled code), if such modules *also* contain PowerShell code and/or [*formatting files* (`*.format.ps1xml`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) or [*type-definition files* (`*.types.ps1xml`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Types.ps1xml).

The most robust solution is to set the desired execution policy on a *per-session* basis, as shown in the linked answer.

---

<sup>[1] The Windows PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).</sup>