# C# pass parameter to power shell script file throws error

Tags: c#, powershell

C# code has to pass parameter value to powershell script file. The code is working fine if I m not paasing any parameter. When I use .AddParameter or AddArgument it throws error.

while using AddArgument  it throws error as  *'A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Test 111'.'*

while using AddParameter  I am getting erro as : *'A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FilePrefix'.'*

Please find my C# code below

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                var scriptfile = @"\\cbc0056\work\Powershell\Scenarios\Test.ps1";

                 ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy")
                 .AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "RemoteSigned")
                 .AddParameter("Scope", "Process")
                 .AddParameter("Force");
                 ps.AddScript(scriptfile).AddCommand("Out-String");

                //ps.AddArgument("Test 222");
                ps.AddParameter("FilePrefix", "Test 222");

                Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject item in results)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Power Shell returned Values as given below " + "\r\n"+item.BaseObject.ToString());
 // write some business logic
                }
```

PowerShelll script Test.ps1 file as given below

```
Param(
[Parameter(Position=1)]
   [string]$FilePrefix
)
$test = $FilePrefix 
Write-Host "hello  this is a test " | Out-String

Write-Host $test| Out-String

$test 

Get-Process | Out-String
```

What is wrong in passing parameter ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to call `AddParameter` _before_ tacking `Out-String` onto the pipeline: `ps.AddScript(scriptfile).AddParameter("FilePrefix", "Test 222").AddCommand("Out-String");`

Comment: but still the parameter value "Test 222" not getting in powershell script. IS there any issue with my powershell script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Use `.AddCommand()` to execute a script *file* (`.ps1`)**; only use `.AddScript()` to execute a script *block*, i.e. a *piece of PowerShell code*.
- As Mathias notes, your `.AddParameter()` call must come *before* adding another pipeline segement with `.AddCommand("Out-String")`.

```
ps.AddCommand(scriptfile).AddParameter("FilePrefix", "Test 222").AddCommand("Out-String");
```

Also note that there's an easier way to set the execution policy, via an object specifying the initial session state: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942672/45375).

Comment: mklement0 - Thank you so much !!!